# Couldn't Understand this unexpected behavior of string and loop in C

Tags: c++, c, string, for-loop, char

here is a screen shot of my C program and its output, it was a problem in a book, i came across.

[image]

[image]

as you can see there is a "for" loop in my code. so what i did was, i changed the value of loop initialization

```
for(i=6;s1[i]!='\0';i++);
```

now the output was again

matrix
Size 6

i changed initialization values again and again and then took output value of "i" as follows

**Initialization ||||  OutPut Value Of (i)**

6          ->            6

7          ->            11

8           ->           11

9          ->            11

10         ->            11

11         ->            11

12         ->            20

**MY Question**

why its not getting me value of i = initialization value of loop ,
whenever I put initialization value of loop > size of entered string(i.e in this case "matrix") ?

because all the char-array element after 6 should be null, shouldn't they ?

Comment: Lol, you can't find any more modern compiler?

Comment: Why to be lazy and print screen your code? Type it here!

Comment: @AbhishekBansal : not working. gives "Size 0Size 1Size2..."

Comment: "because all the char-array element after 6 should be null, shouldn't they?": no, this is an incorrect assumption. Those elements are uninitialized and have indeterminate values.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart : :D..LOL

Comment: If you are indeed coding in C, use `.c` file extension, and remove the C++ tag from your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> because all the char-array element after 6 should be null, shouldn't they ?

No, they don't have to be `\0`. They can hold any value. You just loop until you find the next `0` that happens to be there. When you instantiate an automatic storage array of a built-in type like this:

```
char s[20];
```

there is no initialization performed on the elements. They hold indeterminate values. It is even undefined behaviour to read from them. You can force zero-initialization of the elements like this:

```
char s[20] = {};
```

Comment: Then why it is that everytime I run the program its the 11th or 20th value which is null, because it should be random then ?

Comment: @DemonSocket It's undefined behaviour. It may or may not work the same way all the time.

Comment: @DemonSocket That's undefined behaviour. In theory, it could never find a zero and give you a segmentation violation, or be totally random. In practice, there is always an aligned byte-sized block of zeros somewhere, and it may well depend on the starting conditions. So you may get seemingly reproducible results. But you can't rely on it.

Comment: well ... by the way. it is giving me an error "Expected Expression"

Comment: @DemonSocket my answer is C++, since you tagged your question as such. In C, you might need `char s[20] = {0};`.